# Unable to connect as a client to socket server

Tags: python, sockets

I just started coding in python. I m tring to establish a connection with a telnet client on port number 8888.The problem is that as i enter a single character in the command prompt, it shows, Connection to the host is lost. what should i do ?

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''
PORT = 8888
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket Started'

try:
    s.bind((HOST,PORT))
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Bind Failed'
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Bind Complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listning'
conn,addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected with ' +addr[0] + ' : ' +str(addr[1])
data = conn.recv(4096)
conn.sendall(data)

conn.close()
```

Comment: You are explicitly closing the connection when something is received. What *else* did you want to do?

Comment: Receive a string from the client.

Comment: Well, you're already doing that as well. Receive a string from the client, send it back, then close the connection (last three lines of your code). Did you mean to **print** the data?

Comment: Exactly. That's wat I have been trying.

Comment: ´while "when want server down": conn,addr = s.accept();data = conn.recv(4096);#play with data´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the data, just do it after receiving it:

```
#...
data = conn.recv(4096)
print "received data:", data
#...
```

Comment: This worked for a single character. I m still unable to send a string.

Comment: You may want to read into the `recv` documentation - it will return after receiving 1 to 4096 bytes. If you want to read until EOF, keep reading until you get  `len(data)==0`